# How to update value in Catalog_eav_attribute from UpgradeData

Tags: magento2

So im trying to update the is_visible on update_at attribute which belongs to the product.

Like this

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.4.8', '<='))
        {
            $this->eavSetup->updateAttribute('catalog_eav_attribute', '113', 'is_visible', 1);
        }
```

The code runs, but nothing happens, and the value in is_visible on attribute_id -> 113 is still 0

Comment: make sure updated your modules version in module.xml

Comment: Thank you, it was just magento, that didnt pick it up the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Setup; 
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface 
{
    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
        ) 
    { 
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    } 

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) { 
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(4,135,'is_used_for_promo_rules',1,null); 
        $setup->endSetup(); 
    } 

}
```